# Migrate NFS (data store disks) using Cloudendure tool

Tags: data-migration

How can we migrate data store disks(NFS) using Cloudendure tool to AWS Cloud.

If anyone knows the process, Please share the process steps.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same process , you need to install the agent on your NFS server, check this [link](https://docs.cloudendure.com/#FAQ/FAQ/General_Questions.htm#What_is_there_to_note_regarding_SAN_NAS_Support_)